# Vaermina quest in skyrim

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim

During vaermina quest in skyrim I could either get 'skull of corruption' or make Erandur follow me.... Is there a way to make it both to get the deadric artifact also make Erandur follow me?

Answer (score 2):

Yes and no.  If you are trying for the [Oblivion Walker](http://elderscrolls.wikia.com/wiki/Oblivion_Walker) achievement you will need to collect the skull of corruption (or take advantage of a bug in another quest).

If you just want one to play around while saving Erandur, you can just use a console command if you are on the PC to give yourself one:

> player.additem 35066 1

Answer (score 1):

You can only get one or the other. I killed Erandur and got the skull on my latest playthrough so that I could get the oblivion walker achievement, but if you don't want the achievement I would advise sparing Erandur because the skull of corruption is a trash weapon anyway, it has 20 base damage (which can be increased to 50, but if you have good one handed, two handed or destruction that's still not great).